# YouTube-Video hidden by css not loading in MobileSafari

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari, accordion

On a iPhone-Mobile-Webseite in a jQuery-Accordion there is a «Video»-Content-Box with a embeded YouTube-Video [iframe]. If I load this Page with the «Video»-Box 'open' the YouTube-Video is loading and displaing the Preview-Image perfectly … but if I load the Page with all Boxes closed (display: none … Accordion), MobileSafari will load the Box, but it is empty (but has the right height/height as it has with the displayed video.

On Desktop-Safari the Video will load no matter if the Box is visible or hidden (Accordion) … short: on MobileSafari the video only shows if the box is visible from the start … :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I've used iframe to embed the video … therefore MobileSafari had a problem with the iframe.

If I use the object/embed-code (the 'old' YouTube-Embed-Code), the whole thing works perfectly.